# Oracle Views - EF Core 3.1 - Unable to track an instance of type 'Entity' because it does not have a primary key

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, devart

I try to reload an entity using .NET Framework 4.8 with EF Core 3.1. If I execute the following code:

```
Context.Entry(viewEntity).Reload();
```

I get the following Error:

> Unable to track an instance of type 'ViewName' because it does not have a primary key

I am using an Oracle Database with the Devart provider for the EF Core 3.1. The View itself gets built like this: (Copied from the autogenerated Code by Devart)

```
        private void ViewNameMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ViewName>().HasNoKey();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ViewName>().ToView(@"VIEW_NAME");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ViewName>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName(@"ID").HasColumnType(@"NUMBER").IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
...........
```

A View obviously does not have a dedicated primary key. Does anyone know how to fix the issue? If I try to reload a regular table with a PK, everything works fine. But it is mandatory for me to be able to reload my views as well

Edit: The ID column of the view is only the ID column of the underlying table

Answer (score 0):

You should define an entity key for your ViewName entity in the model. Refer to [How to unit test EF core 3 view with no key in-memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237527/how-to-unit-test-ef-core-3-view-with-no-key-in-memory).

Comment: But if I specify an entity key within the code of the model, doenst it get removed as soon as I use the Entity Developer to recreate my model? Im using at least 30 Views and this could cause problems

Comment: Update From Database Wizard of Entity Developer remembers the choice made once in the wizard. E.g.: you unchecked the change for a view, after this, the corresponding change will be unchecked by default in the next runs of Update From Database Wizard.